# '* as a faster replacement for the dot function in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I was profiling some matlab code and found that my execution time was dominated by calls to `dot`. In the function listing, which is displayed in the profiler, I noticed the following commented line:

> When A and B are both column vectors, DOT(A,B) is the same as A'*B.

Initially my code was running in around 22 seconds, with 17.5 seconds spent in 140976 calls to `dot`. I changed my code to use `'*` instead of `dot` and the **total** run time went down to **14 seconds**! This operator is clearly *much faster* than the function call for taking the dot product of short column vectors.

My question: What exactly is the `'*` operator, is it documented (other than in the source code) and what can/should it be used for?

*For the record: I'm using Matlab vintage R2010b.*

Comment: You can try out `sum(bsxfun(@times,A,B))` too.

Comment: Are you dealing with complex numbers? Guess it won't work then.

Comment: @Divakar, no complex numbers, just two column vectors. In fact I'm taking the square difference between two vectors, so the full expression is `(f-b)'*(f-b)`, where `f` and `b` are two real column vectors of length `5`. I don't know much MATLAB so I wouldn't be surprised if there was a much better method!

Comment: That's weird really, worked for me.

Comment: @TomFenech, `dot` only does the same thing as `A' * B` if the two matrices are column vectors. Both expressions have a meaning if `A` and `B` are full matrices, too, but give different results; they are not equivalent in general.

Comment: A quick optimization since you're looking for sum of squares is just: `sum((f-b).^2)`.

Comment: @Divakar, you are right, `dot` does almost the same as your expression, but you don't need the `bsxfun` since the two matrices are supposed to be of the same size. From the code `dot.m`: `sum(conj(a).*b)`

Comment: @Peter Forgive my ignorance, what is the significance of the `.` before the `^`?

Comment: @TomFenech `.` means element-wise in MATLAB.

Comment: @Peter Would be interesting to see if `sum((f-b).^2)` wins or `'*`!

Comment: Well look at that, A'*A is quite a bit faster than sum(A.^2), on my machine.  Forget my "optimization"

Comment: @TomFenech If `A'*A` doesn't run, something is seriously wrong!

Comment: @Divakar my issue was a badly chosen variable name (`sum`). For the record, of all the suggestions, `(f-b)'*(f-b)` was the fastest in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `'*` operator, it's two operators called sequentially. First `'` i.e. transpose and then `*` i.e. matrix multiplication.

If both `A` and `B` are column vectors, then by transposing `A` to a row vector, the matrix product of the two is equivalent to the dot product, i.e. the sum of all the products of each corresponding element of the two

Comment: Also, if you're doing many dot products, chances are you can "vectorize" them, meaning that you can compute many dot products in one operation, either via a matrix multiplication or via `bsxfun`.  This depends on how your data is organized and the structure of your program.

Comment: If `A` and `B` are matrices then `diag(A'*B)` is the same as `dot(A,B)`

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, I had no idea that `'` meant `transpose` (MATLAB is certainly not my forte). @Peter thanks for your input as well. This operation is still the bottleneck in the code so maybe I could benefit from vectorisation.

Comment: @TomFenech Just a warning: `'` is not transpose. `.'` is transpose. `'` is conjugate transpose

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for the heads up. I'm only working with real values so I tried using `.'` and it makes the code slightly slower than just `'`!

Comment: @Dan, the implementation of `dot` uses `sum(conj(a).*b)`, which is equivalent to but much more efficient than `diag(A' * B)`.

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks, I didn't think to look inside `dot`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are getting the same results? because the dot function performs a dot product between two vectors of the same dimentions while '* performs a matrix product. Ex

```
A=[1 1 1];
B=[2 2 2];
A'*B =  2     2     2
        2     2     2
       2     2     2
```

while

```
dot(A,B)= 6
```

I think that you are thinking of A*B' which is equal to the dot product in the case that your vectors are row vectors.

If your vectors are column vectors, use '*.
To summerize you need your vectors in the form of row*column if you want to perfom a dot product. (which you don't have to think about when using the dot-function ).

Comment: In my case `A` and `B` are column vectors as opposed to rows.

Comment: @user3585110 the `dot` documentation that the OP references explicitly states that the vectors are column vectors

Comment: @Dan, the documentation states that the two operations are equivalent if both vectors are column vectors. `dot` operates with matrices of the same size, too.